# 3 pixels extra space in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

Could someone please work out what's happening here, and how I could fix it? I'm testing [this page](http://www.bookcraft.co.uk/index.php) in IE6, IE7, FF and Chrome, and it works in everything but IE6. In that, there is a small gap between the edge of the chickens picture and the div it's in.

I **hate** IE6.

Comment: +1. We're also stuck with IE6. I feel your pain.

Comment: Does setting display: block on the img fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be the "three pixel jog" bug that shows in IE6 but not later versions of IE.
See http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/threepxtest.html for example.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what it is! Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: It's hurting my brain trying to work this out though. I don't care about IE6 anyway.

Comment: I managed to fix it by un-justifying the text in the div with the chickens in, just in case anyone's interested!

Answer (score -1):

### Using a CSS Reset can help!

Lots of inconsistencies between browsers can be circumvented by using a CSS reset

I use the [Meyer Reset method](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/?reset).

However, another option is the [Yahoo YUI method](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).